# How to dynamically choose between 2 versions of a library?

Tags: c++, cmake, dynamic-linking

I work on a C++ cross-platform project compiled with CMake and use an external library. This library has some issues in an old version, but a disjointed set of issues in a new version. The versions are within the same major release so the API is compatible. I would like to allow users to dynamically (at application startup) select which library version the application should use.

I figure it's a matter of linking to both dynamically, but only loading one, but I'm not very familiar with these aspects.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Do you know about `dlopen` and `dlsym` functions, how they work, and how to use them?

Comment: No, will look them up in depth, but from what I see they seem to be incompatible with Windows ? And this project is cross-platform.

Comment: CMake is really a meta-build tool and more like a project management tool. It doesn't build your project itself, and it definitely isn't involved at run time of your program. So that's kind of a red herring.

Comment: Windows have the [`LoadLibrary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya) and related functions. You can create a wrapper class that handles the libraries on the different platforms you're targeting.

Comment: I see, thanks. I mention CMake because today it links this library in during build already (albeit just one version)

Comment: @JulienBERNARD: "*And this project is cross-platform.*" Dynamic linking is not a "cross-platform" thing; it manifests differently on different platforms. So you're going to have to write platform-specific code for handling it.

Comment: Does the library have a C++ API (with classes etc), a C API, or something else?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to do dynamic linking.   The general approach is to first open the library [based on a filename] and, once the library is opened, retrieve symbols [named using strings] that your program will use, and close the library [release handles, etc] before your program exits - but different systems use different functions to do those things, so the code will be platform specific.   Probably better for your program to make the default choices (e.g. based on libraries it finds at startup) where possible rather than relying on a user to select the library.

Comment: If the user can be bothered to set the `PATH` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variables before startup, you could be able to change the shared lib that is loaded at runtime this way. This would allow you to work without `LoadLibrary`/`dlopen`. This doesn't work, if it's your app itself that needs to the choice at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to build your application twice.  Compilation of your source code will only happen once, but you'll create two executables in CMake linking against the two different versions of the library.  Then you can make a launcher program which starts the desired executable.

There are other solutions too, but they are more work and less portable.

Comment: This assumes the libraries are ABI compatible. Since the author only mentioned API compatibility I'd rather assume that they're not ABI compatible. In particular because apparently the name of the library file itself changed. Usually ABI compatible versions will have the same name, in which case the problem wouldn't exist in the first place. So you'd need to compile the application twice, too.

Comment: They're ABI compatible as far as I know, which I didn't think to mention. Thing is this project (which isn't mine) is part of a larger project including a launcher. PRing in a library extraction and a toggle is one thing, but I doubt PRing a split into two executable to be chosen among by the launcher for this particular bug (and there are many) would fly - at least it wouldn't if I was the maintainer.

Comment: @JulienBERNARD: you should ask the project maintainers how they want this handled.  If the library has a narrow C API (just a few functions to call), you could use `dlopen()` and `dlsym()`, but that approach will be annoying if there are many functions or the library has a C++ API.

Another idea: edit one of the two shared libraries, renaming all its symbols with some prefix or suffix to distinguish them.  Then you can use both versions because without name collisions.  E.g. `patchelf --rename-dynamic-symbols`: https://github.com/NixOS/patchelf/commit/da035d6acee1e5a608aafe5f6572a67609b0198a